# mySQL performance one huge database vs small many

Tags: mysql

I am developing a site that has many subdomains in it.

It has blogging module, management system, and many more. I have shared this question in various sites but couldn't get a proper reply.

Question is should I use one database for all the modules, this means my database would have nearly 100 tables. Is this approach be appropriate or should I create separate database for every module?

Comment: 1. Do something "right" 2. Optimise if necessary 3. Go to #1

Comment: Now seriously: which car is faster, a blue one or a red one?

Comment: MySQL is perfectly capable of supporting 100 tables, and many more.

Comment: @zerkms That's not really fair. It's obvious that color has no bearing on a car's speed, but it's not so obvious if the number of tables impacts MySQL performance.

Comment: @mpen that's my exact point: the overall performance has nothing to do with the chosen parameter.

Comment: Um... You guys have experience. I also have but never have thought outside of university projects. Now it is the time. I am learning and thank you for your concern. Appreciate it really

Comment: @Alen so learn this thing then: performance is not the absolute property. Nothing is guaranteed to be "the best from performance perspective" solution ever. You implement something, profile/measure, then improve, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does not really matter.

If you use innodb with single data file (innodb_file_per_table setting is not enabled), then all data will be stored in a single file anyway.

With innodb separate file per table mode or with myisam table engine, the only difference between one or multiple databases is really the directory where the database files are stored. Unless the directories (databases) are located in different storage devices with different speeds, their performance will be the same.

There can be 2 reasons to keep some tables in a different database:

1. Security: mysql does not support role based access control. Therefore if there is a group of tables that should be accessible by a certain group of users only, then the access control is more manageable if those tables are in a different database.
2. If some of the modules you mentioned happen to use the same table name, then you will have to move them to a separate database or you need to modify the code and table names to avoid errors.

Comment: Highly appreciated sir.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong way to design a system.  Just advantages and disadvantages to the various techniques.  I normally work in Oracle and SQL Server so I had to look up some terms for MySQL.  According to my research, in MySQL a database is synonymous with a schema which changes things.  I'd consider these things when planning the physical design for any vendor:

- Security - Do all subdomains need read/write to each other?  How are the users secured?  Choosing one or many schemas can impact how easy schema and user security is to manage and control.
- Growth - Do some subdomains grow at a faster rate than others?  If yes, I'd consider separating them to allow for the different growth rates.
- Organization - Is it easier to identify the different subdomains in practice if they're separated?  If you don't separate them, use a strong naming convention so you can easily identify objects within one subdomain.
- Linking - How easy is it to access one schema/database from another?

Hope this helps.